# VBA ARRAY definition does not work for global definitions

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I define PIXEL_DATA as a global with

```
Dim PIXEL_DATA() As Variant
```

I initialize it using the ARRAY function in a subroutine.  And while I am in that subroutine, PIXEL_DATA has the appropriate data in it.

But when I try to access from another subroutine

```
 Ptr = PIXEL_DATA(2)
```

I get "PIXEL_DATA" blued out and the error message "Compiler Error: Not a Sub or Function not defined".

What am I missing?

Comment: `Dim` only makes that variable available to the module the variable is located in (assuming the variable is declared at the top of the code module).  So if your `PIXEL_DATA` is declared in `Module1` but you're trying to access it from, say, a userform, then you'll get that error.  If you want it to be truly global, change `Dim` to `Public`.  Generally speaking though, public variables are best avoided where possible, though there are circumstances where their use is warranted.

Comment: `Dim` is always local. Avoid confusion, keep `Dim` for local variables, and use `Private` for module-level variables; use `Public` to declare globals... *if* you really need a global variable (most likely, you don't) - consider using parameters instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the key component of *where* you're `Dim`ing `PIXEL_DATA()`. Here's an example:

```
Sub MainSub()

   Dim PIXEL_DATA() As Variant
   PIXEL_DATA = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   Call OtherSub

End Sub
Sub OtherSub()

    Dim Ptr As Long
    Ptr = PIXEL_DATA(2)
    Debug.Print Ptr

End Sub
```

Running `MainSub()` will resulting in a compile error highlighting `OtherSub()` because `PIXEL_DATA()` is out of scope. But moving `PIXEL_DATA()` to the **modular** level compiles, runs and returns 3 to the immediate window as expected:

```
Dim PIXEL_DATA() As Variant
Sub MainSub()

   PIXEL_DATA = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   Call OtherSub

End Sub
Sub OtherSub()

    Dim Ptr As Long
    Ptr = PIXEL_DATA(2)
    Debug.Print Ptr

End Sub
```

If your `OtherSub()` is in an entire other module, then you'll need to declare is as `Public` like @tigeravatar mentioned above.